# Need help casting from a List<String[]> to an Array

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, casting

I am using the csvparser library from univocity and am having trouble converting a List object in to an array that would be easily read from.

The method that keeps throwing an ArrayStoreException is:

```
List<String[]> resolvedData;
String[] array = new String[7000];

public void parseURLs() throws FileNotFoundException {

    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    try {
        resolvedData = parser.parseAll(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\kevin.anderson\\Desktop\\book1.csv"));
        resolvedData.toArray(array);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());

    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the items out of a List into an array or is there an easy way to iterate thru the items in the List string array?

Thank you

Comment: How are you going to put `String[]` values into a `String[]`?

Comment: Why do you want the data in an Array?

Comment: I presume that each line, which is captured by a `String[]`, is captured in the list.  The next question would be, what do you intend to do with the result?

Comment: @TangledUpInBlue:  [That's how the API mandates it.](http://docs.univocity.com/parsers/1.3.0/com/univocity/parsers/common/AbstractParser.html#parseAll(java.io.Reader))

Comment: I would like to pass each value into a string variable and use it later

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a beginner problem, but well stated and backed up by what has been tried.  It's also probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) but that is typical for beginners and shouldn't merit a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    List<String[]> resolvedData;
    String[][] array;

    public void parseURLs() throws FileNotFoundException {

        CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
        settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
        CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

        try {
            resolvedData = parser.parseAll(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\kevin.anderson\\Desktop\\book1.csv"));
            array = new String[resolvedData.size()][];
            resolvedData.toArray(array);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

Basic errors you assumed a fixed size of the incoming list of 7000 and also a single dimension array which is addressed with

**String[][] array = new String[resolvedData.size()][];**

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  There is no need to convert the data to an array in order to iterate over it, so I'll give the answer I *think* you're looking for, which is how to iterate *easily* over a `List<String[]>` that you're receiving from the CSV parser.

```
for (String[] currentLine : resolvedData)
{
    // currentLine here is a String[] containing the fields from one CSV record
    // To iterate over the fields
    for (String field : currentLine)
    {
        // do something with each field
    }
 // --- OR ---
    // To access fields by index
    String firstField = currentLine[0];
    // do something with firstField
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this `ArrayStoreException` because the list `resolvedData` contains `String[]` elements and not `String`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

@Daruisz is right. `resolvedData.toArray()` will produce an array of arrays:

```
    String[] array1 = {"1a", "1b"};
    String[] array2 = {"2a", "2b"};
    String[] array3 = {"3a", "3b", "3c"};
    List<String[]> data = Arrays.asList(array1, array2, array3);
    String[][] arrayOfArrays = data.toArray(new String[0][0]);
```